# What does Vehicle other = (Vehicle)obj; do?

Tags: java

I'm confused to what `Vehicle other = (Vehicle)obj;` does. Does it create a variable `other` and copies `obj` into it?

```
@Override
public boolean equals (Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) return true;
    if (!(obj instanceof Vehicle)) return false; 

    Vehicle other = (Vehicle)obj;
    return ( type.equals(other.type) 
            && size == other.size
            && uitstoot == other.uitstoot
           );
}
```

Comment: It does nothing like that. It casts a reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you check if the `obj` is instance of  `Vehicle`

`if (!(obj instanceof Vehicle)) return false;`

If it is then it is cast to `Vehicle` class - i.e from that point onwards, it will be interpreted as `Vehicle` instance

```
Vehicle other = (Vehicle)obj;
```

Comment: This equals method is implemented in the Vehicle class, does this mean that you need to override the equals method in every class if you want to use equals in that class?

The equals() in Object class is only doing the instanceof check.
See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html

Comment: Yes. You have to override `equals` AND `hashcode` in every class you want to be able to compare for equality or use in `collections`.

More info:http://www.technofundo.com/tech/java/equalhash.html

Answer (score 0):

It does two things. It declares `other` to be a `Vehicle` reference, and it initializes it as a pointer to the object that is referenced by `obj`. The cast will never cause a runtime exception, because that object has already been determined to be a `Vehicle`.

Comment: That does make a lot of sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct.

First it transform the Object obj to Vehicle class ( we already checked the obj could be transformed to Vehicle class, otherwise code couldn't go to here )

Second give the copy to the other variable in order to protect original data.